# Apache: require with satisfy, and v2.5 compatibility

Tags: apache-2.4

I want to protect an entire server with `Require valid-user`, but I want to allow certain resources to be accessible without a login. For the sake of argument, say that files `A`, `B`, and `C` should be public. I've tested this requirement with the config below:

```
<Location "/">
  ...
  AuthType openid-connect
  Require  valid-user
</Location>

<Directory "/var/www/data">
  Require all denied
  <Files "A">                                                                                           
   Allow from all
   Satisfy Any
  </Files>
  <Files "B">
    Require all granted
    Satisfy Any
  </Files>
  <Files "C">
    Require all granted
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

For this config, `A` and `B` work as expected (the files can be viewed without a login), but `C` doesn't work.

The configuration for file `A` (with `allow` and `satisfy`) is [recommended](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#satisfy) by the 2.4 documentation (under "Another frequent use of the Satisfy directive is to relax access restrictions for a subdirectory").

The config for file `B` is the obvious equivalent without `allow`, but still requires a `satisfy`, since the config for file `C` doesn't work.

The problem is that `satisfy` is deprecated in 2.5, so how do I get this to work for 2.5? `RequireAny` only works within a single directory, unlike `satisfy`, so doesn't seem to be the right answer. I haven't tested a `RequireAny` that encloses all of `AuthType`, `Require valid-user`, and `Require all granted` for every resource that has to be public - there must be a better way.